# MS Access 2007 Keyword search within form to generate report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

My Set-up: I have two tables: tblAuthors and tblBooks. tblAuthors includes a list authors: Kurt Vonnegut, Frank Herbert, J. K. Rowling, John Nichols, etc.. tblBooks includes a list of books: Slaughter House Five, Cat's Craddle, Monkey House, Dune, Harry Potter, Milagro Beanfield War, etc..

tblBooks includes a memo coloumn called 'excerpts'. This section contains a small paragraph from each novel that has special significance or meaning.

I have two forms as well: frmAuthor and frmBooks. frmAuthor includes the name of the author as well as some more author specific information that isn't particularly relevant to this question (date of birth, place of birth, preffered genre, inspirations, etc.). frmBooks includes the authors name(s) as well as some other information (publishing company, date completed, genre).

I am currently using the filter function to generate reports within my forms. I am currently just using it to find simple stuff (Author name or genre). I was hoping that I would be able to generate reports by using the excerpt section from my form. I would like to be able to search a common word (e.i. God, Snake, Horse, Church, House, Road...) or phrase so that is within excerpt. That way I can generate a report with common themes.

Please let me know if I need to clarify this at all, I know it may seem a bit convoluted. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you want the report to be based on `tblBooks` and filtered by `author_name` (from `frmAuthor`) and a word selected on one of the forms (`frmBooks`?).

So, if I've interpreted this correctly, and if `frmAuthor` includes a text box named `txtAuthor` and frmBooks includes a text box named `txtSearch` where the user inputs a word from the excerpts field, see if a query like this returns the rows you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblBooks
WHERE
        author_name = Forms!frmAuthor!txtAuthor
    AND excerpts Like '*' & Forms!frmBooks!txtSearch & '*';
```

If that query suits after substituting your actual control names, you could use it as the record source for your report.  (But `SELECT` an actual list of field names instead of `SELECT *`)

Alternatively you could use an unfiltered query as the record source for your report and open it by feeding that `WHERE` clause (without the word `WHERE`) as the *WhereCondition* parameter to `DoCmd.OpenReport`:

```
Dim strWhere As String
strWhere = "author_name = Forms!frmAuthor!txtAuthor" & _
    " AND excerpts Like '*' & Forms!frmBooks!txtSearch & '*'"
Debug.Print strWhere
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", WhereCondition:=strWhere
```